# Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Trying to use the plugin to manage database on the mobile device, SQLite, through the ngCordova implementation, but it shows me the same error every time I try to create the database. The phone have **Android 4.2.2**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined
```

#### My code, add the the ionic and ngCodova for using the plugin's

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
    .run(startApp)
    .controller('networkCtrl', networkCtrl)
    .factory('databaseFtr', databaseFtr);
```

#### Start App

```
startApp.$inject = ['$ionicPlatform'];

function startApp($ionicPlatform) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }

        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

    });

}
```

#### Controller

```
networkCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'databaseFtr'];

function networkCtrl($scope, databaseFtr) {
    databaseFtr.crearDB();
}
```

#### Factory

```
databaseFtr.$inject = ['$cordovaSQLite'];

function databaseFtr($cordovaSQLite) {

    return {

        crearDB: function() {

            var db;

            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
                name: "mydata.db",
                location: 'default'
            });


        }

    }

}
```

Here is the capture showing the plugin install

[image: plugin install]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use

```
 window.sqlitePlugin.openDB({
            name: "mydata.db",
            location: 'default'
        });
```

Instead of

```
$cordovaSQLite.openDB({
            name: "mydata.db",
            location: 'default'
        });
```

Comment: I found the solution, can't start the database the same time with the app

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to the problem, which was completely unknown.

The reason why this problem is generated is because the creation and opening of the database is intended to originate at the same time as the application tries to start, and since the database can not exist without having started the application , Because the method of creation of this, it is not possible to be executed.

The solution that applies in my case, is that the database was created after running a function through the command `ng-click`.

#### Code

```
function networkCtrl($scope, databaseFtr) {

    $scope.dbProcesos = {

        dbCreate: function() {
            var db;
            db = databaseFtr.crearDB();
        }

}




function databaseFtr($cordovaSQLite) {

    return {

        crearDB: function() {

            var db;

            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
                name: "patologias.db",
                location: 'default'
            });

            return db;

        }
    }
}
```